# fft and array-to-image / image-to-array-conversion

Tags: python, image-processing, fft

I want to make a fourier-transformation of an image.
But how can I change the picture to an array?
And after this I think I should use numpy.fft.rfft2 for the transformation.
And how to change back from the array to the image?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) library to load/save images and convert to/from numpy arrays.

```
import Image, numpy
i = Image.open('img.png')
i = i.convert('L')    #convert to grayscale
a = numpy.asarray(i) # a is readonly

b = abs(numpy.fft.rfft2(a))

j = Image.fromarray(b)
j.save('img2.png')
```

I used `abs` above because the result of the FFT has complex values so it doesn't really make sense to convert it directly to an image. The conversion to grayscale is done so that the FFT is done on a single channel only - you can choose another way to pick a channel instead, or pass the correct `axes` parameter to `rfft2` and later extract the channel you need.

**Edit:**

To also perform an inverse FFT and get back the original image, the following works for me:

```
import Image, numpy
i = Image.open('img.png')
i = i.convert('L')    #convert to grayscale
a = numpy.asarray(i)

b = numpy.fft.rfft2(a)
c = numpy.fft.irfft2(b)

j = Image.fromarray(c.astype(numpy.uint8))
j.save('img2.png')
```

Comment: When I make an inverse fft, i dont get the real image back. Why?

Comment: @kame Because the call to `abs` loses data. Also, the source image should be grayscale, otherwise you'll get a 3D array instead of 2D.

Comment: @kame: I added code to show how you can do an inverse FFT. I'm guessing this is what you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This wasn't obvious. :)

Comment: TypeError: Cannot handle this data type

Comment: @Cerin: I'm guessing you didn't convert the image to grayscale as shown in the second example. It doesn't really make sense to FFT a 3-channel image and convert the result to an image. I''ll add this to the first example as well. Next time try asking instead of immediately downvoting.